# Clear a keymap for a mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Sometimes I need to redefined the whole map of a mode. That means that I am not interested in the default bindings, it is undesired to accidentally use some default keybinding when no remapping was assigned.

For example, I define `dired-mode-map` as

```
(evil-define-key 'normal dired-mode-map
   ....
```

How can I clear all the default keybindings before mapping my own?

Comment: `(setq dired-mode-map (make-keymap))` should do it, no?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the same like with the logscia's solution: `Wrong type argument: keymapp, nil`.

Comment: Make sure you start from `emacs -Q` (no init file) when trying things like this. If you don't see the same problematic behavior with `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: It would help if you turned on `debug-on-error` and then posted the backtrace. The error that you report could have any number of causes (including user error in your init file as @Drew suggests).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```lisp
(setcdr dired-mode-map (cdr (make-keymap)))
(set-keymap-parent dired-mode-map special-mode-map)
```

That is, it creates a new empty keymap and replaces the contents of `dired-mode-map` with that.  It happens to work because a keymap is a list whose car is just the symbol `keymap`, so the cdr is all that needs to be changed.

Comment: When I do this I get `easy-menu-get-map: Wrong type argument: keymapp, nil` in `fundamental-mode` buffers when I call `dired-jump`.

Comment: But `(make-keymap)` returns a list whose `car` is the symbol `keymap`, so replacing the `cdr` is wrong. I believe @Drew has it right in the comment.